# HttpContextBase.Request exception when using Ninject MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

I have a service that takes a dependency on HttpContextBase.

Ninject is injecting this for me already as it's set up in the MvcModule to return `new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)` when HttpContextBase is requested

I want to use this service in Application_AuthenticateRequest, so i'm using property injection so that Ninject resolves it for me

When I try and access Request.UserHostAddress on the HttpContextBase I get a `Value does not fall within the expected range` exception

If I call `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress` directly it works without problems

ExampleService.cs

```
public class ExampleService : IExampleService {
    HttpContextBase _contextBase;

    public ExampleService(HttpContextBase contextBase) {
        _contextBase = contextBase;
    }

    public void DoSomething() {
        var ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;  <== this works
        ip = _contextBase.Request.UserHostAddress;  <== this fails
    }
}
```

Global.asax

```
[Inject]
public IExampleService ExampleService { get; set; }

public void Application_AuthenticateRequest() {
    ExampleService.DoSomething();
}
```

I'm missing something here, but I can't see what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependencies that are injected into classes live as long as the the class they get injected into, because the class holds a reference to them. This means that in general you should prevent injecting dependencies that are configured with a lifetime that is shorter than the containing class, since otherwise their lifetime is 'promoted' which can cause all sorts of (often hard to track) bugs.

In the case of an ASP.NET application, there is always just one `HttpApplication` instance that lives as long as the AppDomain lives. So what happens here is that the injected `ExampleService` gets promoted to one-per-appdomain (or singleton) and since the `ExampleService` sticks around, so does its dependency, the `HttpContextBase`.

The problem here of course is that an HTTP context -per definition- can't outlive a HTTP request. So you're storing a single `HttpContextBase` once, but it gets reused for all other requests. Fortunately ASP.NET throws an exception, otherwise you would probably be in much more trouble. Unfortunately the exception isn't very expressive. They could have done better in this case.

The solution is to **not** inject dependencies in your `HttpApplication` / `MvcApplication`. Ever! Although it's fine to do so when you're injecting singletons that only depend on singletons recursively, it is easy to do this wrong, and there's no verification mechanism in Ninject that signals you about this error.

Instead, always resolve `IExampleService` on each call to `AuthenticateRequest`. This ensures that you get an `ExampleService` with the right lifetime (hopefully configured as per-web-request or shorter) and prevents this kind of error. You can either call into the `DependencyResolver` class to fetch an `IExampleService` or call directly into the Ninject `Kernel`. Calling into the `Kernel` is fine, since the `Application_AuthenticateRequest` can be considered part of the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/):

```
public void Application_AuthenticateRequest() {
    var service = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IExampleService>();
    service.DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: I understand that there's one instance of HttpApplication and that when using `[Inject]` I would have a long running instance of IExampleService, but I thought as the only dependency of the service was HttpContextBase (which references the static HttpContext.Current) and Ninject creates a new one each time it's requested, I would be ok. Your answer works perfectly

Comment: On each HTTP request, the `HttpContext.Current` returns a different `HttpContext` instance. You pass on one instance (of those many instances) into the `HttpContextWrapper` and that wrapper is reused for the lifetime of the application.